# How to map a modifier key + key to a single key? (example: Shift+M2 to E)

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, mapping

I play a game that uses `WASD` for movement that also uses `Q` and `E` for abilities.

With this hotkey setup, I cannot hit `E` while moving up and to the right (holding down `W` and `D`), because both those fingers are being used. I have to momentarily stop moving to do this.

Instead, I'd like to be able to map `Shift+M2` (M2 = Right mouse button) to `E`, so I can cast it without ever having to take my fingers off `WASD`.

The game does not let me do this. That is, it doesn't allow for modifier keys to be added to abilities in the game settings.

I am looking for a program or solution that allows me to perform this remappping. That is, a tool that can map `Shift+M2` to `E`.

Ideally, this would be easy to toggle on and off so that I can disable it when I stop playing.

I'm using Windows 10.

Is there a way to do this that isn't just writing a script in a language like AutoHotkey? I'd prefer something more low-level and tailored, as AutoHotkey has been finicky in the past for me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) is able to remap keys and keycombinations at will with few restrictions, as far as I know.

You just have to [write a simple script](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) for it.

Whether it will work well or at all inside your application/game or not is another matter.